# Remove trailing space from \input

Tags: input

It seems that `\input` appends a trailing space.  MWE:

**foo.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}                                                         
\begin{document}
foo\input{bar.txt}baz
\end{document}
```

**bar.txt**

```
bar
```

Which, using `pdflatex foo` gives the output `foobar baz`, with a space in between.  How do I remove it?

Comment: `\input{bar.txt}\unskip baz`